# How to extends multiple classes, in php?

Tags: php, symfony, extends

I would like to create a form in my "contactus" page.
I'm following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_2/en/01-Form-Creation).
I have to extends the sfFrom class to use sfWidget, but in my code I've already extends BaseController.

Is there any solution to do this without making a new class?

```
class InfoController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/contactus", name="info_contactus_page")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function contactusAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can make the same. In this post C class is created at the top of the file, but mine it's a symfony class. Can you help me?

Comment: @rabudde not at all. Did you read the **full** question ?

Comment: @Tom-pouce are you working with symfony 1 or 2? Because `BaseController` doesn't exist in symfony1 but in sf2. And then, you are reading the wrong tutorial ..

Comment: Also I just noticed, controller should never extend sfForm. controller in some action should create instance of custom sfForm child and work with it. The whole question does not make any sense

Comment: @j0k I'm working on Sf2. I can't find any Symfony2 tutorial to create form... =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing all wrong.

symfony 1 is **completely different** than Symfony 2 (check this article: [*How Symfony2 differs from symfony1*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html)). You follow a tutorial from sf1 to create form in sf2.

You should instead try to find resources for sf2, like :

- [Official Form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)
- [Lots of recipes in the official Form Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/index.html)

And since you're french, I recommend you to read these tutorials:

- [Les formulaires dans Symfony2](http://www.lafermeduweb.net/tutorial/les-formulaires-dans-symfony2-p100.html)
- [Créer des formulaires avec Symfony2](http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-523899-creer-des-formulaires-avec-symfony2.html)

Then, when you will have read these tutorials, you can come back here to ask a new question about a problem you got when implementing a form.

Comment: I didn't see that my tutorial was for sf1. =/ Thanks for the remark I was seeking solution for hours...

Answer (score 0):

use composition or interfaces.

In your case composition is solution.

PHP does not allow multiple inheritance

Comment: What? I mean if you have for example class A { }, then you can "inherit" class A behavior in class B with class B { public/private/protected $instanceOfA; }  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP5.4, use traits:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

```
<?php 

trait SomeOtherControllerTrait {
    function SomethingSomethingSomething() { /* Something */ }
}

class InfoController extends BaseController {
    use SomeOtherControllerTrait;
    /* ... */
}
```

They allow you to get similar result to multiple inheritence by using composition.

EDIT: Since the tags underneath the question changed to Symfony2: 
You don't need the multiple inheritance since Symfony2 handled this situation in a different way. The accepted answer described it well.

Comment: I've to instantiate a sfFrom object (in the function SomethingSomething...) ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that and have it available in the InfoController. Nevertheless it's not the Symfony2 way of doing things ;)